# Difference between にさせる vs にする（as in 幸せにさせる vs 幸せにする)

Tags: word-choice, causation

What's the difference when we say 幸せにさせる compared to 幸せにする?

I'm now confused between using させる and にする.

Can anyone please provide an in-depth explanation?

Answer (score 10):

…を幸せにする means “to make … happy.”  させる is the causative form of する.  Therefore:

> AがBを幸せにする: A makes B happy.
>   XがAにBを幸せにさせる: X makes A make B happy.

However, some people may confuse these two and say 幸せにさせる when they mean 幸せにする.

Answer (score 2):

The correct one is 幸せにする, because する is usually the causative form of なる/である.

But it seems that when the object is a person, させる is often used instead of する as a light verb.

```
うれしくさせたい
つらい思いをさせないで
幸せな気持ちにさせる
```

する, なる, である, etc. are used in the active sense.

```
好きにしろ
つらい思いをする
幸せな気持ちになりたい
```

So it is understandable that some people may say 幸せにさせる unconsciously.