# Difference between 人を不安にさせる and 人を不安にする

Tags: grammar, causation

I came across this sentence during immersion:

> 人を不安にさせといてそりゃないでしょ!!!

Why is 不安にさせといて and not 不安にして in this case if the meaning is "to make people anxious"?

Comment: Related: [Difference between にさせる vs にする（as in 幸せにさせる vs 幸せにする)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/7051/5010)

Comment: For some reason 不安にさせる sounds much more natural than 幸せにさせる.

Answer (score 4):

Focusing on 不安にさせる/不安にする, both sound ok to me, so 人を不安にしといて works. But probably 不安にさせといて is more common.

I guess that this would be best understood simply as a pragmatic fact for learners.

---

[This paper (pdf will download)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/198566509.pdf) cites a seemingly relevant reult:

> I : 感情形容詞の連用形に後接するスル-サセル置換では「サセル」が、属性
> 形容詞の連用形に後接するスル-サセル置換では「スル」が優先される傾向
> にある。
>
> Ⅱ：感情形容詞・属性形容詞の種別を問わず、形容詞の連用形に後接するスル
> -サセル置換では、Ｘ項（ガ格）が非情物であるのが典型となる。
> （森 2004 , p.37）

Note this seems corpus-based and does not give any definite rules.

---

FYI: some other examples

- 幸福にさせる(0) is not acceptable. 幸福にする(21) is the only option.
- 不愉快にさせる(1)・不愉快にする(4) are both fine.
- 不快にさせる(9) sounds more natural than 不快にする(5)

The parenthesized numbers are results returned by [BCCWJ](https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/string_search). Also 不安にさせる/不安にする = 23/2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker, but my feeling is that the 'させる' part emphasizes that it is someone else's experience.  'にする' is more for things that are for you and affect you.

Comment: What’s someone else’s experience? Feeling anxious, or making someone anxious?