# What is the meaning of this line ? ぬめり感を狂おしくさせた。

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

**ぬめり感を狂おしくさせた。**I don't understand this line so if anyone can please correct me if I'm wrong .Does this mean

1/ "The slimy feeling make me crazy"

or 2/ "(I feel) The slimy feeling increased like crazy " ?
P/s: added context

> > The full context is MC's thought during a H-scene with a girl (A-san)
> >  生真面目な口調が快感に上擦って乱れるのが、妙に艶めかしい。

> > その自分の言葉にA-sanは昂ぶってしまい、**愛液の分泌が増して幹肌と膣壁が擦れ合うぬめり感を狂おしくさせた。**  (I get the first part of this sentence , but wondering about 2nd part )

Comment: Can you provide more context? Like the title of that visual novel?

Comment: I don't think either of your options are correct. I'm pretty sure the meaning is that something or someone made something extremely slimy. ぬめり感 is the object and is being acted upon by a subject not mentioned in your example.

Comment: All I'm seeing is a very basic `AをBする` pattern, and you probably know this already. If you couldn't make sense of it within the context or the sentence, [provide the whole context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010), as always.

Comment: Well its NFSW kind of context in a visual novel ,so I don't know if i should post it here (maybe with spoiler to hide it ? )

Comment: I guess the usage is a bit vague anyway, but at least the subject should be included to get an answer. My feeling is that it says something like *due to the subject, the slimy feeling is intensified  so that I felt crazy*.

Comment: Can you include the full sentence and the previous context using the spoiler tag?

Comment: how to use spoiler tag in edit mode , i did not see any

Comment: Take time to read https://japanese.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: I added spoilers now

Comment: I believe your interpretation 2 is likely. 狂おしくさせる applies to the noun phrase「幹肌と膣壁が擦れ合うぬめり感」(slimy feeling of 膣壁 rubbing against pp). For the させる part, it might be helpful to read this question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/90676/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AをBくする](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%84-adjective-%E3%81%8F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-ku-suru-meaning/) means "to make A B". 狂おしい in this context is a positive expression meaning "(extremely) fascinating" or "maddening", not "mad". Basically the sentence is saying "the secretion made the slimy feeling all the more fascinating/maddening/irresistible" or something.