# にさせる usage in a sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, particle-に

I was reading the Japanese version of No Longer Human by Osamu Dazai, and this sentence came up.

> 嫌な気持ちにさせるのだ

I would like to know why に particle was used before the word させる.

Answer (score 1):

This grammar can be broken down into two parts:

First of all, `にする` is a grammar point on its own (see https://www.kanshudo.com/grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B for reference), which in this case carries the meaning of `causing a state to be so`.

The verb する is then changed to させる in its **causative**  for, emphasizing the negative nature of the 嫌な気持. (See: [Difference between にさせる vs にする（as in 幸せにさせる vs 幸せにする)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/difference-between-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b-vs-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-as-in-%e5%b9%b8%e3%81%9b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b-vs-%e5%b9%b8%e3%81%9b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b) and [Difference between 人を不安にさせる and 人を不安にする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/90676/difference-between-%E4%BA%BA%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B-and-%E4%BA%BA%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B))

Comment: So, にする is a set rather than two components. If I use にする means "I make something", but if I use にさせる means "it makes me...", something like this?